# Can 'it' be used plurally?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, phrases, verbs, sentence

Can 'it' as a pronoun refer to many different imperative verbs? For instance, in the sentence:

> Abide by thy customs, thou excellent one: **grind** thy corn, **drink** thy water, **praise** thy cooking,-- if only **it** make thee glad!

Comment: Think of "it" here as meaning _whatever you do_.

Comment: The *it* here is not referring to all and certainly not any one of the things listed before. The reference is to the action (verb) *abide*. (How to abide is detailed in the list, which is parenthetical.)

Answer (score 4):

What that *it* is really referring back to is the single imperative verb that started the whole thing off: ***Abide***.  The other imperative verbs are just a list of example customs that you might be abiding by.  You can leave them out without changing the meaning of the sentence:

> Abide by thy customs, if only it make thee glad!

Comment: Riggght. Now, I see. So it cannot be used plurally like that? Thanks--now I get it!

Answer (score -1):

"It' is generally used to describe a single item, I think with the quote, that 'it' refers more to the single act of the customs rather than the three listed items.